# Transactions in Graph Engine

Tags: graphengine

Is it possible to implement transactions in Graph Engine?

I like to do multiple updates on different cells and then commit or rollback these changes.

Even with one cell it is difficult. When I use the next code the modification is not written to disk but the memory is changed!

```
using (Character_Accessor characterAccessor = Global.LocalStorage.UseCharacter(cellId, CellAccessOptions.StrongLogAhead))
{
    characterAccessor.Name = "Modified";
    throw new Exception("Test exception");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is: Regardless of you throwing this Exception or not: The changes are always only in memory - until you explicitly call `Global.LocalStorage.SaveStorage()`.

You could implement your transaction by saving the storage before you start the transaction, then make the changes, and in case you want to rollback, just call `Global.LocalStorage.ResetStorage()`.

All this, of course, only if you do not need high-performance throughput and access the database on a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

The write-ahead log is only flushed to the disk at the end of the "using" scope -- when the accessor is being disposed and the lock in the memory storage is about to be released.

This is like a mini-transaction on a single cell. Others cannot access the cell when you hold the lock. You could do multiple changes to the cell and "commit" them at the end -- or, making a shadow copy at the beginning of the using scope, and then rollback later to this copy when anything goes wrong (this is still a manual process though).

Also, please check this out: https://github.com/Microsoft/GraphEngine/tree/multi_cell_lock
We are working on enabling one thread to hold multiple locks. This will make multi-entity transactions much easier to implement.